# Flat UI proの適用ができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Flat UI Pro デザインフレームワークを [reflection/designmodo-flatuipro-rails](http://joanswork.com/add-flat-ui-pro-to-rails/) を使って、Rails4.2 のプロジェクトにインストールしようとしています。
[参考サイト](http://joanswork.com/add-flat-ui-pro-to-rails/)の手順でやっているのですが、うまく適用できません

---

**STEP1**

- `Flat-UI-HTML-Developers-License.zip` をダウンロードしてデスクトップに解凍
- 解凍後のフォルダ名は `Flat UI HTML - Developers License`
- 上記のフォルダ名を `flat-ui-pro` に変更

プロジェクトのコンソールから`bower.json`ファイルが有るディレクトリに移動し、`bower install`

1. `cd`
2. `cd Desktop`
3. `cd flat-ui-pro`
4. `cd HTML`
5. `cd UI`
6. `cd Flat-UI-Pro-1.3.2`
7. `bower install`

---

**STEP2**

```
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'designmodo-flatuipro-rails', '~> 1.3.2.0.branch'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

bundle update
bundle install
```

**STEP2 後の `app/assets/stylesheets`**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

**STEP3**

プロジェクトのカントディレクトリにて

```sh
bin/rails generate flatuipro:install ~/Desktop/flat-ui-pro
```

**STEP3 後の `app/assets/stylesheets`**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**STEP3 後の `http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts`**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

**STEP4**

```sh
rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=development
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development
```

**STEP4 後の `app/assets/stylesheets`**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**STEP4 後の `http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts`** 変化なし

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

**STEP5**

```sh
rails generate flatuipro:demo
```

**STEP5 後の `app/assets/stylesheets`**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**STEP5 後の `http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts`** 変化なし

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**STEP5 後の `http://0.0.0.0:3000/flatuipro_demo/index`**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**`scaffolds.scss` を削除した後の `http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts`**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**`scaffolds.scss` を削除した後の `http://0.0.0.0:3000/flatuipro_demo/index`**
**配置やレイアウトが変**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**select boxが変**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]